# Content-Type in Post query ajax. Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Send ajax request without a header. Node.js an error:

> { [Error: unsupported content-type] status: 415, statusCode: 415 }

But, if a request with a header, then does not react node.js

My ajax function:

```
function ajax() {
var http = createRequestObject();
if (http) {
    var callback, url, method, obj, params='';
    var len_args = arguments.length;
    if (len_args == 4) {
        url = arguments[0];
        method = arguments[1];
        params = arguments[2];
        callback = arguments[3];
        if (method == 'post') {
            //http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multiparty/form-data');
            //http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            //http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multiparty/form-data');
        }
    } else if (len_args == 2) {
        url = arguments[0];
        method = 'get';
        callback = arguments[1];
    }
    http.open(method, url, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            callback(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
else {
    //document.location = url;
}
```

}

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multiparty/form-data');`
Do `http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');` (where we changed `multiparty` to `multipart`).

Comment: Did not help. 
if set a blank header, then node.js will not responde:
http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', '');

Why?

So:
http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', '');
Is not wirking.
So:
http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type2', '');
Is not wirking.
So:
http.setRequestHeader('', '');
Is not wirking.

Why?